# How to format docker ps output to not use relative times?

Tags: docker

I am running the command `docker ps -a --format "{{.ID}}\t{{.Status}}\t{{.Names}}"` which produces output like

```
55b7db4d6a97    Exited (0) About an hour ago    rails-test-interactive_rails_1
6fa969b9b558    Up About an hour    rails-test-interactive_postgres_1
774e9a35e2df    Exited (0) 2 hours ago  loving_babbage
```

However, I'm trying to parse this with a perl script, and the relative times are, quite frankly, a complete pain in this scenario.

Is there a flag I can pass to replace `About an hour ago` with `00:00:58:47` — that is, number of days, number of hours, number of minutes, number of seconds?

I've had a look at the `docker ps` documentation, but it doesn't say anything particularly useful on the subject (and "go template" is a search that gets lost in the weeds all too quickly :)

Comment: I hate these relative dates, they are everywhere. I wish a painful death who invented that :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `docker inspect` is the way to go as it lets you make queries for particular properties of a container. For example, to get the start time of all the running containers,

```
docker inspect --format='{{.ID}} {{.State.StartedAt}}' $(sudo docker ps -q)
```

Note that it takes multiple arguments and arguments are container IDs.